# How can I return JSON with all modules?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I would like to get my JSON with all modules like this:

```
[
 {
  "id":"1",
  "seccion":"Inventario",
  "data":
    [
     {
     "id":"11",
     "icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/assets\/img\/sidebar\/items.png",
     "value":"Productos",
     "seccion_id":"1",
     "url":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/inventario\/product"
     },
     {
      "id":"14",
      "icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/assets\/img\/sidebar\/employees.png",
      "value":"Provedores",
      "seccion_id":"1",
      "url":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/provedor\/provedor"
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "id":"2",
     "seccion":"Compras",
     "data":
      [
       {
       "id":"22",
       "icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/assets\/img\/sidebar\/suppliers.png",
       "value":"Compras",
       "seccion_id":"2",
       "url":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/compras\/compras"
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
```

But my JSON is returning this:

```
{
 "seccions":
 {
   "0":
   {
    "id":"22",
    "icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/assets\/img\/sidebar\/suppliers.png",
    "value":"Compras",
    "seccion_id":"2",
    "url":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/compras\/compras"},"index":1
    }
 }
```

The controller is just returning my last module, but I dont know why. How can I fix it and change my controller method to return all modules?

**Controller**

```
public function getModules($module_id){
     if ($this->session->userdata('log')){
         $data = $this->session->userdata('log');
         $menu = array();
         $seccions = $this->module->get_rows();
         foreach ($seccions as $index => $seccion) {
             $modules = $this->module->query("SELECT CONCAT('".$seccion['id']."',storelte_modulo.id) AS id,CONCAT('".base_url('assets/img/sidebar')."','/',storelte_modulo.icon) as icon, storelte_modulo.modulo AS value,storelte_modulo.seccion_id,CONCAT('".base_url()."',storelte_modulo.url) AS  url FROM storelte_modulo INNER JOIN storelte_modulo_perfil ON  storelte_modulo_perfil.modulo_id = storelte_modulo.id WHERE seccion_id = $seccion[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.perfiles_id = $data[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.STATUS = 1");
             //assuming you get 1 row only from the above query
             if (!empty($modules)) {
                    $modules['index'] = $index;
                    $menu['seccions'] = $modules;
             }
         }
         foreach ($seccions as $item) {
             array_push($menu,$item);
         }
         $this->json($menu);
         $this->load->view('modules_view',$menu);
     }
 }
```

**Model**

```
public function get_rows(){
    $this->db->select('id,seccion');
    $this->db->from('storelte_seccion');
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}

public function query($query){
    return $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="row">
<h3 class="text-center">Welcome to storeLTE, click a module below to get started!</h3>
<div class="home_module_list">
    <div class="module_item">
        <?php foreach ($seccions as $session) { ?>
          <div class="module_item" title="<?= $session['value'];?>">
            <a href="<?= $session['url']; ?>"><img src="<?= $session['icon']; ?>"/></a>
            <a href="<?= $session['url']; ?>"><?= $session['value']?></a>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your results in the first "foreach" with this statement:

```
$menu['seccions'] = $modules;
```

In every cycle, if the SQL query is successful, you simply overwrite all previous data by current value.

It later corresponds to the output:

```
{
 "seccions":
 {
   "0": { ... }
 }
}
```

Your controller code should go like this:

```
public function getModules($module_id){
    if ($data = $this->session->userdata('log')){
        $seccions = $this->module->get_rows();
        foreach ($seccions as $index => $seccion) {
            // Consider using fetchAll() or similar method
            $seccions[$index]['data'] = $this->module->query("SELECT CONCAT('".$seccion['id']."',storelte_modulo.id) AS id,CONCAT('".base_url('assets/img/sidebar')."','/',storelte_modulo.icon) as icon, storelte_modulo.modulo AS value,storelte_modulo.seccion_id,CONCAT('".base_url()."',storelte_modulo.url) AS  url FROM storelte_modulo INNER JOIN storelte_modulo_perfil ON  storelte_modulo_perfil.modulo_id = storelte_modulo.id WHERE seccion_id = $seccion[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.perfiles_id = $data[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.STATUS = 1");
        }
        $this->json($seccions);
        $this->load->view('modules_view', $seccions);
    }
}
```

Just consider using fetchAll() or similar method after $this->module->query() to fetch all data at once.

Comment: how can I do it? can u give me a example how can I get the json with all modules?

Comment: Do it like this: $menu['seccions'][] = $modules;

Comment: how can I do it or Access to my view?

Comment: Have you tried the Controller code attached to the answer?